# Why can't I read next page of json data from website into json buffer?

Tags: android, json, uri, httpurlconnection, androidhttpclient

I m doing book finder android app, it fetches data from website of ebooks, displays 10 books per page, when I press next button it should display next 10 books.

> http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/java&type=title

The above url gives me a json array of books on **the first page**, it looks like this:

> {"Error":"0","Time":0.0043,"Total":"327","Page":1,"Books":[{"ID":1542146786,"Title":"Java Phrasebook","Description":"Java Phrasebook gives you the code phrases...............................
>   and so on

this url -  http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/java&type=title**&page=5**

should give me next chunk of json data on **page 5**

I do build valid url but my httpUrlconnection method that reads using GET request method **always gives me only first page** - even if I form url for page 5.

This is the method that establishes URL connection and stores into buffer from given URL:

```
private String MakeConnectionAndStoreBufferData(String validUrl){
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;


    URL url = new URL(validUrl); 
    // even if this url has &page=5 at the end
    // it still fetches data for page = 0

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.connect();

    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(line + "\n");
    }

    return buffer.toString();
```

EDIT: at Rami, here I show how i actually build my URL addresses - **I do check them after I build them, they look as expected**:

```
public class ProcessData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private String createValidURL(String query, int page_counter) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "create Valid url......");

    String BASE_URL = "http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search";

    String resultUrl = null ;
    if (page_counter == 0){

        destinationURL = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendPath(query)
                .appendQueryParameter("type", "title")
                .build();

    resultUrl = destinationURL.toString();


}
   else if(page_counter > 0){

        destinationURL = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendPath(query)
                .appendQueryParameter( "type", "title")
                .appendQueryParameter("page",  Integer.toString(page_counter) )
                .build();

        resultUrl = destinationURL.toString();

    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "before we return url, it is :" + resultUrl);
    return resultUrl ;
}


public String doInBackground(String ...params) {

    String validUrl = createValidURL(params[0], 5);//5 is page counter        
    String result_buffer = MakeConnectionAndStoreBufferData(validUrl);
    return result_buffer ;
    }
    }
```

This is mainactivity.java, I do search for books with title "java":

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // create valid URL, connect to it-ebooks website, read buffer, parse buffer to return complete list of books

    ProcessData data = new ProcessData();
    data.execute("java");//this calls doInBackground in processData class!
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you build the url of the next pages? I think there is something wrong there, this is why you always get the first page

Comment: @Rami, yes , look for the post, i will post it under edit at rami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/java?type=title&page=5
```

After careful observation i found the mistake - it was about ? sign after word java.

Basically you can write ....java?type=title&pa and it will still load the first page! the website is "forgiving" and will return the first page by default **if the query is illformed - if page is missing, incomplete etc**

I could not find it other way! the only problem is the java ? -question sign, 
anyways, nobody could help me here, i m glad i found the bug myself!

I should make sure my url has replaced ? with &.

p.s. be careful about creating urls: append query parameters may make almost correct URL.

Answer (score 1):

**Your MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btnPrev, btnNext;
static int page = 1;
TextView txtview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnPrev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);

    callServer(page);
    btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (page > 1) {
                page = page - 1;
                callServer(page);
            }
        }
    });
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            page = page + 1;
            callServer(page);
        }
    });
}

protected void callServer(int pageNumber) {
    new ParserClass(MainActivity.this, new CalbackListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
            try {
                String pageNo = result.getString("Page");
                txtview.setText("Page No : " + pageNo);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, page).execute();
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.soapsample.MainActivity" >

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Previous" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/previous"
        android:text="Next" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**JsonParser.java class**

```
public class ParserClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

private ProgressDialog dialog;

public interface CalbackListener {
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject result);
}

private int page;
private CalbackListener callback;
private String url = "http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/java&type=title&page=";
private Context context;

public ParserClass(Context context, CalbackListener callback1, int page) {
    this.callback = callback1;
    this.page = page;
    this.context = context;
    this.url += String.valueOf(this.page);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Title", "Loading...", true);
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {

    String result = null;

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        Log.i("url", url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        if (httpGet != null) {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.i("Result", result);
        }
        return new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    dialog.dismiss();
    callback.onSuccess(result);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks, i solved the problem it does load different book covers depending on pages - thanks!